# Retrieve html from server and display with Angular

Tags: html, angular, service

I'm trying to retrieve HTML from a REST service and display it using Angular (4.3). I can watch the service get called and return the correct content. However, the angular component using this never seems to actually receive the content. What have I missed?

Specifically a `console.log(html)` (in the second code sample below) always outputs null.

I have an angular service that looks like:

```
@Injectable()
export class SlidesService {

    private requestUrl: string;

    constructor(
        @Inject(AppConfig) private config: AppConfig,
        @Inject(HttpClient) private http: HttpClient) {
        this.requestUrl = this.config.restRoot + listSlidesUrl;
    }


    getSlide(deck: string, slide: string): Observable<string> {

        const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Accept': 'text/html'});
        const thisUrl: string = this.requestUrl + '/' + deck + '/' + slide;

        return this.http.get<string>(thisUrl, { headers: headers });
    }
}
```

This is used by a component:

```
export class SlidePreviewComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() slide: string;     /* Identifier for the slide */
    @Input() deck: string;
    slideHtml: string;


    constructor(private slideService: SlidesService) {

      }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.slideService.getSlide(this.deck, this.slide)
            .subscribe(html =>  this.setSlideHtml(html) );
    }

    setSlideHtml(html: string) {
        this.slideHtml = html;
        console.log(html);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you watching the service get called/return the correct content (console.log in service, console.log in subscribe, or are you looking at your browser's XML)? First guess is that the returned response is an object not a string so it doesn't know how to parse, but there's not enough info here to pinpoint.

Comment: Watching as in "I've got the application server running locally and I'm tracing the outputs"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The new [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#httpclient) class expects the `get()` method to return JSON response. If you expect a text (HTML), it's [necessary to specify it](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data) in the request options:

```
this.http.get(thisUrl, { headers: headers, responseType: 'text' });
```

The special `Accept` header may be unnecessary then.

Answer (score 8):

Hi can you try this in service

```
 getSlide(deck: string, slide: string){
   const thisUrl: string = this.requestUrl + '/' + deck + '/' + slide;
   return this.http
        .get(url ,{ headers: headers, responseType: 'text' })
        .toPromise()
        .then(resp => resp.text())
        .catch(error=>console.log(error))
}
```

and your component

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.slideService.getSlide(this.deck, this.slide)
            .subscribe(html =>  this.setSlideHtml(html) );
    }
setSlideHtml(html) {
        this.slideHtml = html;
        console.log(html);
    }
```

in your template

```
<div id="scroll" [innerHTML]="slideHtml"></div>
```

Comment: That also solved the problem but the accepted one changes my code a great deal less. Thanks.