# Can Angular @Component template dynamic loading from backend

Tags: angular

Question is if i put Angular template html in database.

And use api to get template from database.

And render template in Angular Component.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Angular Version lastest.

Comment: Using [innerHtml] you'll be able to do it,
https://stackoverflow.com/q/46327430/11004482

stackblitz demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inner-html-cdw3qs

Comment: nop, it's not possible. Angular not "compile at time". Only if the "template" has "pure html+pure javascript" you can do it